# Attributes and Behaviours in game object design

Tags: architecture, component-based, behavior

Recently I have read interesting slides about game object design written by Marcin Chady [Theory and Practice of the Game Object Component Architecture](http://www.gdcvault.com/free/gdc-canada-09). I have prototyped quick sample that utilize all Attributes\Behaviour idea with some sample data.

Now I have faced a little problem when I added a RenderingSystem to my prototype application. I have created an object with RenderBehaviour which listens for messages (OnMessage function) like MovedObject in order to mark them as invalid and in OnUpdate pass I am inserting a new renderable object to rederer queue. I have noticed that rendering updates should be the last thing made in single frame and this causes RenderBehaviour to depend on any other Behaviour that changes object position (i.ex. PhysicsSystem and PhysicsBehaviour).

I am not even sure if I am doing this the way it should be. Do you have any clues that might put me on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb there is no right or wrong way of doing the rendering, it all depends on your architecture and game.

Rendering is usually done outside of the component based system, despite this you will either reference your models from a renderable system where the updates on position will be done or the models will fetch the latest animations frame and position themselves before each draw.

Usually I simply duplicate data (position, skeleton, animation) and sync it when needed.